# Excel Links to possible sheets in data file turning #REF

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a report.xlsx file that pulls data from sheets on data.xlsx.
The sheets in the data file are named data-1, data-2, data-3, etc
Directly linking the files is great "=data-3!$a$1", but if data-3 isn't in the data file I get a #REF error. (#REF!$a$1)

The total number of sheets in the data.xlsx file changes from period to period.
I have used the indirect function to stop the #REF problems, but now the recalculating and updating is a slow process.
Ex: where A1 holds the number 3 or 2 or ....
 =indirect("data-"& A1 & "!$a$2")
There are over 300 data sheets possible.

Does anyone have a formula solution that doesn't use indirect or any other volatile formula?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use IF formula and trap the error, return 0 or default value if error occurs? 
something like
= if(ISREF(something), default_val, something)

Comment: Because when the worksheet is no longer in the Data file, the sheetname portion turns to #REF.